# Kafka Spark Streaming json file with varying schema

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, databricks, spark-structured-streaming

I have created a pipeline to consume streaming data from kafka topic which is in json format. But the problem is the jsons files with varying schema. so when I apply schema on the dataframe, it produces corrupted record.

How can I handle the varying schema in kafka streaming in Databricks using Pyspark

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches here, depending on what kind of schema variation is in your topic:

- if all schemas have the compatible data types (no columns with the same name but with different types), then you can just create a schema that is superset of all schemas, and apply that schema when performing `from_json`.
- if your schemas are incompatible, for example, you have fields that have the same name but different data types, then you can read data as text lines first, and then decode with different schemas depending on the row type - suppose that all JSONs have the `type` field with string type (not tested):

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = spark.readStream.format("kafka")....load().withColumn("value")\
  .withColumn("value", col("value").cast("string"))
df_typed = df.withColumn("jsn", F.from_json(F.col("value"), "type string"))\
  .select("value", "jsn.*")
df1 = df_typed.filter("type == some_value)\
  .withColumn("jsn", F.from_json(F.col("value"), schema1)).select("jsn.*")
# process df1
```